# Qemu-ARM user emulation. Error when using Go

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go, arm, qemu

I want to customize an image I created for an ARM device (Odroid C1+). Especially I want to checkout some git repositories and install their dependencies.

But when installing go libraries, this bug is happening: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13024

Is there a workaround? Or do you know another user emulator (or similar) to do this?

Comment: I think they say it will not work anymore....

Comment: @RickyA Okay. It is written something like that too in my link. But then my question is, if there is another possibility to customize my image? Is there another emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to use full system emulation in QEMU - just find an ARM kernel that boots in qemu-system-arm and instead of chrooting into the file system from the host, do it from within QEMU.